# Create WPF GridView Columns Automatically

Tags: wpf, gridview

I need to create a table structure that will automatically create columns for a collection of objects (the structure of which is pretty flexible). The data in the table will only be read only so I've been looking into using a GridView but can't figure out how to automatically generate the columns - has anyone got an example or a URL explaining how to do it?

I'm not totally adverse to using the DataGrid control included as part of the WPF ToolKit, but it seems a little over-kill for displaying readonly data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at this post on generating the columns for a GridView:

[WPF GridView with a dynamic definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356144/wpf-gridview-with-a-dynamic-definition)

Using the DataGrid would definitely be overkill.