# wpf binding code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In code i add columns to listview successfuly. But i want add binding to column than add to listview.

fist is working code in xaml.

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="colName" Header="Name" Width="130">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Values, Converter={StaticResource LoadProfileConverter},ConverterParameter=active_total}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Code behind:

```
GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
column.Header = "Header";
column.Width = 130;                     

FrameworkElementFactory controlFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

var itemsBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Values")
{
    Converter = new LoadProfileConverter(),
    ConverterParameter = "active_total",
};

controlFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, itemsBinding);

DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
template.VisualTree = controlFactory;

column.CellTemplate = template;

LoadProfileGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: Please reread yourself before you post.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx How to: Create a Binding in Code

Comment: @ShadeOfGrey but here nothing about ConverterParameter ((

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var itemsbinding = new Binding("Values")
            {
                Converter = new LoadProfileConverter(),
                ConverterParameter = key
            };

        controllerFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, itemsbinding);
```

Create a proper binding using the code above.

Loads of extra properties on the binding object that can assist you.

Comment: looks good, when a see i think this is what i need, but not works :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356144/wpf-gridview-with-a-dynamic-definition  try reading through that question. In a quick glance your answer could be there.

Comment: here they use DisplayMemberBinding , i just check not works again

Comment: no , no errors , simply no data in that culumns , and in column that i write binding in xaml - there is exists data.

Comment: Can you debug in your converter and see if they correct values are coming in?

Answer (score 0):

```
 GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
                            column.Header = key;
                            column.Width = 130;                     

                            FrameworkElementFactory controlFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

                            var itemsBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Values")
                            {
                                Converter = new LoadProfileConverter(),
                                ConverterParameter = key

                            };                           

                            column.DisplayMemberBinding = itemsBinding;
                            LoadProfileGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```