# Telerik WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I am using Telerik RadGridiew for a table GUI. Since it is supposed to be used for any MySQL table, the row and columns of the table is not known at compile time. For some of the columns, they could be foreign keys, in which case I'd like to use a combo box for that column's cell editor to allow the selection of these foreign keys. However, it appears that Telerik does not support the autogeneration of combo box columns. So is there some way I can somehow hijack the autogeneration process and put in the combo box column at some point?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/357306/1517578

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, since this is a third party extension to the WPF grids.